# Go through set of numbers and getting all possible matches

Tags: regex, vb.net, iteration

I'm trying to go through a set of numbers like "123456789123456" and I want to be able to find every single combination of numbers I can, that is 8 long, and it's starting point increasing by 1 for every match.

I'll use [] as where the expression starts, and then counts from.

Example:

```
First match: [1]23456789123456 would find: 12345678
Second match: 1[2]3456789123456 would find: 23456789
Third match: 12[3]456789123456 would find: 34567891
```

and so on...

I'm fairly new to Regex so I don't have a ton of experience in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need regex for this.  Just a simple loop should do:

```
Dim input As String = "123456789123456"
For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 8
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(i, 8))
Next

12345678
23456789
34567891
45678912
56789123
67891234
78912345
89123456
```